# Inserting into Array (C#)

Tags: c#

I am trying to insert an `int` value in `int array` at the user input index and getting an error: `Index was outside the bounds of the array`. The error is in the while loop, but the solution does not use any methods like `Array.Add` etc.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the length of Linear Array");
int length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] LinearArr = new int[length];
Console.WriteLine("Maximum number of input : {0}",length);
for (int i = 0; i < LinearArr.Length; i++)
{
    LinearArr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.WriteLine("What number you want to insert and at what index");
int InsertNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Number :{0} and Index :{1}",InsertNum,k);

while (length>=k)
{
    LinearArr[length + 1] = LinearArr[length];
    length = length - 1;
}
LinearArr[k] = InsertNum;
length = length + 1;
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your while loop condition from:

```
while (length >= k)
```

to:

```
while (length > k)
```

as in current condition it will access last index which is not in the array.

Another mistake is your array is of size of value in the `length` variable:

```
LinearArr[length]
```

and in while loop you are accessing index greater then array length:

```
LinearArr[length + 1] = LinearArr[length]; // length +1 will give out of bounds error
```

Comment: And also `Console.WriteLine("Maximum number of input : {0}",length);` should be `Console.WriteLine("Maximum number of input : {0}", length - 1);`. This is probably the root cause, a misunderstanding of array indices and their length.

Answer (score 1):

When you define

```
int[] LinearArr = new int[length];
```

the valid indexes are `0`..`length-1`. Therefore, this expression causes an out-of-range exception:

```
LinearArr[length + 1] = LinearArr[length];
```

neither `length` nor `length+1` are valid indexes.

In order to fix this problem, allocate enough space in the array, and start moving elements at `length-1`:

```
int[] LinearArr = new int[length+1]; // Make space for an expansion
...
while (length > k) {
    LinearArr[length] = LinearArr[length-1];
    length--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a `List<int>` instead of an `int[]` as it provides an `Insert` function.